# Which conditions / situations / place / moment is there a purple moon in the sky in?

Tags: the-moon, color

According to this [A purple moon?](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/article/photographer-marcella-giulia-pace-moon-colors)

In March 12, 2017 there was a purple moon somewhere , "just risen, color altered red moon". I've seen yellowish, redish moons, but I've never seen a purple moon. Which conditions / situations / place / moment is there a purple moon in the sky in? Can it be predicted where and when it will appear? Does this appear only in some specific part of the world?

Comment: APOD's answer is "unclear": https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap201111.html